# Update Table using JOIN and Inside Query

Tags: t-sql, sql-update

I have imported a Members table which has invalid States.  Instead of having the State Abbreviation, it contains the completed State Name.

The below query does work and pulls up the Members.StateName and State.Abbreviation :

```
Connecticut CT
Maryland    MD
Massachusetts   MA
```

Now I am trying to write and Update command where I am replacing the Members.StateName with the State.Abbreviation .

```
UPDATE dbo.Members
SET memState = (SELECT s.stAbv FROM dbo.State AS s
JOIN Members AS m ON s.stName = m.memState )
WHERE memState NOT IN (SELECT s.stAbv FROM dbo.State AS s)
```

*ERROR: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

The statement has been terminated.
I understand the error says my inside query returns multiple rows, so it can not Update.  How do I get this to work?

Comment: Do you have more than one state row in dbo.State with the same name?  If you do - shouldn't one or other be deleted / flagged as deleted - or tied to a particular country, if you've US states, UK counties, etc. in the table?

Comment: The below code worked

    UPDATE dbo.Members
    SET memState = (SELECT TOP 1 s.stAbv FROM dbo.State AS s
    JOIN Members AS m ON s.stName = m.memState )
    WHERE memState NOT IN (SELECT s.stAbv FROM dbo.State AS s)

Comment: Are you sure that's what you're after though?  Will the abbreviation returned by a TOP 1 be the abbreviation for 'the right' state?  Why'd you have > 1 state with a particular name in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do it like this:

```
UPDATE m
SET memState = s.stAbv
FROM dbo.Members AS m
  INNER JOIN dbo.State AS s ON s.stName = m.memState
```

Not entirely sure about your WHERE clause, but most probably it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign more than 1 value to memState. Try SELECT DISTINCT to join duplicate values to one value.